# Modeling data for maximum searchability

Tags: database, riak

What's the best way to model this data:

```java
public class Item {
    Double price;
    String geoHash;
    Long startAvailabilty; // timestamp
    Long endAvailabilty; // timestamp
    Set<String> keywords;
    String category;
    String dateCreated; // iso date
    String dateUpdated; // iso date
    Integer likes;
    Boolean isActive;
}
```

As such it will be possible to query and search for the ff:

- Price range
- String "starts with" query (geo hash search)
- Timestamp range (similar to price range)
- Keyword search (search from a set of string)
- Equality (for category etc)
- ISO Date string search
- Boolean search (search w/c one is active)

For the Riak KV database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above, I can imagine this being implemented either via maps, possibly containing sets with [map reduce](https://www.tiot.jp/riak-docs/riak/kv/2.2.6/developing/usage/mapreduce/)/[secondary indexes](https://www.tiot.jp/riak-docs/riak/kv/2.2.6/developing/usage/secondary-indexes/) or by using [Yokozuna (Solr)](https://www.tiot.jp/riak-docs/riak/kv/2.2.6/developing/usage/search/).

Despite this, the above data set looks more like it should be in a relational database than a non-SQL database. For something in the middle, you might want to consider [Riak TS](https://www.tiot.jp/riak-docs/riak/ts/latest/) ([download](https://files.tiot.jp/riak/ts/1.5/1.5.1/)) which is similar to KV but has a thin SQL layer on top. The current version (1.5.1) is a bit old but we plan to launch an improved version later this year with additional SQL features available.

Comment: What's the advantage and disadvantage of using Riak TS?

Comment: Also why map-reduce is required here? Isn't 2i enough? Can you shed some light?

Comment: I'm actually compelled into thinking that this complexity can run on top of Riak KV, and btw I am thinking of just packing the data into a platform-independent serialization like MsgPck: https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java then just put secondary indexes.

Comment: Advantage of using Riak TS - SQL based querying with the power of Riak behind it.
Disadvantage of using Riak TS - SQL is not a full implementation yet. Other solutions may do it better at this point in time.

Map-reduce is just an alternative to 2i. If you can do it with 2i, that should be fine then.

I've not used msgpack, personally, but many of our Riak support customers have found ingenious ways to store and access their data, so that does indeed sound like a valid way to start going about it. I think play with different tools in a dev environment and find what fits your needs best.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I also wonder btw, who's the main maintainer for Riak KV now that Basho has been acquired? And who may be the core commiters?

Comment: You'll find most of us in the Postriak Slack channel. Incidentally, bet365 purchased Basho's IP and kindly made it open source. As far as I know nobody actually bought Basho once it went into receivership.